# How to export backup of Cloud SQL database in Google Storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a GAE project and for that to store the data i have used Cloud SQL database. 
I need to take **on demand backup** of my Cloud SQL database and the backup should be stored in google storage.

Can anyone help me to how can i do this programatically using JAVA?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot export a backup (on-demand or automated), as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#can_i_export_a_backup). What you can do however is to export your data to a SQL dump file or a CSV file, depending on your use case, and store it on Cloud Storage.

There is no Java utility to perform an export but Google exposes an API endpoint for you to trigger an export. Here's an example request using standard curl tool:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{"exportContext":
                {"fileType": "SQL",
                 "uri": "gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/<PATH_TO_DUMP_FILE>",
                 "databases": ["<DATABASE_NAME1>", "<DATABASE_NAME2>"] }}' \
   -X POST \
   https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances/[INSTANCE_NAME]/export
```

You'll find further details about exporting data in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting).

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to restore backups cross project without separately exporting each database of an instance separately. See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/restoring#projectid

You can use all rest calls, or a combination of gcloud and rest calls. An older answer here is using `curl`, so mine will as well, since that is what is presently works and this question shows up in Google.

Get the backup id you want:

```
gcloud sql backups list --instance=SOURCE_SQL_INSTANCE_ID \
  --project=SOURCE_PROJECT_ID
```

It will list entries with the following format in reverse chronological order. Choose the one you want.:

```
ID: SOURCE_BACKUPID
WINDOW_START_TIME: 2023-12-23T02:26:07.357+00:00
ERROR: -
STATUS: SUCCESSFUL
INSTANCE: SOURCE_SQL_INSTANCE_ID
```

Restore the backup to another server in another project:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d '{
          "restoreBackupContext": {
            "backupRunId": "SOURCE_BACKUP_ID",
            "project": "SOURCE_PROJECT_ID",
            "instanceId": "SOURCE_SQL_INSTANCE_ID"
          }
        }' \
    "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/TARGET_PROJECT_ID/instances/TARGET_SQL_INSTANCE_ID/restoreBackup"
```

The response will come back in this format:

```
{
  "kind": "sql#operation",
  "targetLink": "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/TARGET_PROJECT_ID/instances/TARGET_SQL_INSTANCE_ID",
  "status": "PENDING",
  "user": "chris.chiasson@example.com",
  "insertTime": "2023-12-23T04:44:21.223Z",
  "operationType": "RESTORE_VOLUME",
  "name": "RESTORE_OPERATION_ID",
  "targetId": "TARGET_SQL_INSTANCE_ID",
  "selfLink": "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/TARGET_PROJECT_ID/operations/RESTORE_OPERATION_ID",
  "targetProject": "gluca360-prod"
}
```

You can check your results with the following command:

```
gcloud sql operations list --instance=TARGET_SQL_INSTANCE_ID \
  --project=TARGET_PROJECT_ID
```

You may see a status similar to the following:

```
NAME: RESTORE_OPERATION_ID
TYPE: RESTORE_VOLUME
START: 2023-12-23T03:46:33.132+00:00
END: 2023-12-23T04:05:01.731+00:00
ERROR: -
STATUS: DONE
```

Answer (score 0):

While LundinCast's answer is still correct und provides helpful information it is outdated to some extend.

**New Java Utilities introduced**

Google now privides a Java Utilities for it which can be be found here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances/export

In my opinion the example code given there lacks the minimum code for how to set the request body. So I provide a simple snippet here:

```
var exportContext = new ExportContext();
// gs:// stands for the gsutil tool, the filename should have "gz" as file extension
exportContext.setUri("gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/<BACKUP_FILENAME.gz>");     exportContext.setDatabases(List.of("<DATABASE_NAME>"));
exportContext.setFileType("SQL");

var requestBody = new InstancesExportRequest();
requestBody.setExportContext(exportContext);
```

**Neccessary permissions and automatisation**

The Java Utility might not work out of the box because you'll need to set some permissions/roles correctly. A complete recipe (which also covers automatisation e.g. every day) can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/scheduling-cloud-sql-database-exports-using-cloud-scheduler . Unfortunately (as of 2022-04-21) the Python script is outdated (and also examples for other languages are missing). Use the first link given in my answer instead to see newer implementation.

**Testing upfront via gcloud**

To test the export step it might even help to test it via gcloud first:

```
gcloud sql export sql <CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE> gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/<BACKUP_FILENAME>.gz --database=<DATABASE_NAME>
```

(you might have to set you project first via `gcloud config set project <PROJECT_NAME>`)